# How to implement tabs with routes, when URL parameters are also contained in the route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have followed this very simple example of how to implement tabs with routes: https://codedaily.io/tutorials/45/Create-Nested-Tab-Routes-with-Dynamic-Paths-with-React-Router

The problem is,  my routes have url parameters, so I can't use `match.path`, else I end up with unresolved url params (`/:userId/comments/`) so I decided to use `location.pathname` instead, but this has it's own problems. For example if I navigate to the contact tab, then to comments and back to contacts, my URL would look like: `/USERID-13984123/contact/comments/contact`. Storing the original `location.pathname` in state causes similar problems when using back navigation, after navigating away from the page.

Does react-router provide any out of the box way to work around this issue?

Update: I wrote an algorithm which takes `match.path` and returns a new path string with the url params resolved, which fixes the issue, but it seems a bit hacky, so am still open to suggestions.

Comment: Could checking just the last part of the path work? I've dealt with a similar issue in a project recently and done it this way.

Comment: I did think of that, but it wouldn't work too well for me because the previous part of my path is a user defined ID. I think working around that would lead to much more hacks than my current solution.

Comment: I know, you can use `NavLink` for your tabs from `react-router-dom` if you didn't do that already.